# Add prefix to every line in text in bash

Tags: bash, text, awk

Suppose there is a text file `a.txt` e.g.

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

I need to add a prefix (e.g. `myprefix_`) to every line in the file:

```
myprefix_aaa
myprefix_bbb
myprefix_ccc
myprefix_ddd
```

I can do that with `awk`:

```
awk '{print "myprefix_" $0}' a.txt
```

Now I wonder if there is another way to do that in shell.

Comment: You can do it with just `bash` (rather than calling `sed/awk/perl/python/etc` as external executables) but you're better off using the best tool for the job which, for this simple case, is probably `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: I fully agree, `awk` looks an overkill, that's why I am asking this question. How would you do it with `bash` ?

Comment: I wouldn't. I'd do it with `sed` exactly as @fedorqui has shown.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pure bash:

```
while read line
do
    echo "prefix_$line"
done < a.txt
```

Comment: I'd do `read -r line` here…

Comment: @jno your comment would be much more useful if you explained why and perhaps provided a link.

Comment: one may read `help read` output in bash, for instance.
The `-r` switch makes the `read` to read "raw" text without handling `\\`-continuations, for instance. Those continuations is not usually what you want prefixing strings in a stream.  

>       -r do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

Comment: Right, so using `read -r` makes sense unless your actual data format treats a trailing `\` as a line continuation.  So if your data format is program source code, `read -r` might not be what you want (you might want to add a prefix only to the "logical" lines, not the "physical" ones).

Comment: Actually, any `\X` sequence will be interpreted without that `-r` flag.
Yes, it's up to implementer to decide is it what she want or not.

Answer (score 28):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^/myprefix_/' a.txt
myprefix_aaa
myprefix_bbb
myprefix_ccc
myprefix_ddd
```

This replaces every line beginning `^` with `myprefix_`. Note that `^` is not lost, so this allows to add content to the beginning of each line.

You can make your `awk`'s version shorter with:

```
$ awk '$0="myprefix_"$0' a.txt
myprefix_aaa
myprefix_bbb
myprefix_ccc
myprefix_ddd
```

or passing the value:

```
$ prefix="myprefix_"
$ awk -v prefix="$prefix" '$0=prefix$0' a.txt
myprefix_aaa
myprefix_bbb
myprefix_ccc
myprefix_ddd
```

It can also be done with [`nl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nl):

```
$ nl -s "prefix_" a.txt | cut -c7-
prefix_aaa
prefix_bbb
prefix_ccc
prefix_ddd
```

---

Finally: as [John Zwinck explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831827/add-prefix-to-every-line-in-text-in-bash/19831852?noredirect=1#comment29489578_19831852), you can also do:

```
paste -d'' <(yes prefix_) a.txt | head -n $(wc -l a.txt)
```

on OS X:

```
paste -d '\0' <(yes prefix_) a.txt | head -n $(wc -l < a.txt)
```

Comment: +1 for the `sed` solution, where using `awk` or `Perl` is like swatting a mosquito with a thermo-nuclear warhead :-)

Comment: Thanks! I like the `sed` solution and did not know about `nl`.

Comment: Or with horror: `paste -d'' <(yes prefix_) a | head -n $(wc -l a)`.  It would be a lot better if paste had an option to stop at the first EOF rather than continue until all EOFs.

Comment: Didn't know about the `yes` command, @JohnZwinck, it sounds cool. However, it is not working to me, just shows the file `a`.

Comment: Here's a version that works on OS X: `paste -d '\0' <(yes prefix_) a.txt | head -n $(wc -l < a.txt)` - on Linux you probably need to say `''` instead of `'\0'` but the rest should work.

Comment: That's such a trick, @JohnZwinck, now it works to me. I would add this to your current answer not to be hidden here in comments :)

Comment: No, I like my current answer as it is--you're welcome to add that monstrosity to your answer though--I wrote it specifically in the spirit of your several examples!  :)

Comment: While the `awk` solutions are good, they are redefining `$0` which indicates that `awk` will waste time with recomputing the fields and the variable `NF`. It might be better just to do `'{print "prefix_" $0}'` or avoid concatenation with `'{printf "prefix_%s\n", $0}'`

Comment: Your `nl` solution is fabulous, and I improved it slightly to make it stable and universal, ---------------------  `nl -w1 -s" $prefix" | cut -d' ' -f2-`

Answer (score 12):

For reference, regarding the speed of the `awk`, `sed`, and `bash` solution to this question:

Generate a 800K input file in `bash`:

```
line="12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
rm a.txt
for i in {1..10000} ; do
    echo $line >> a.txt
done
```

Then consider the bash script `timeIt`

```
if [ -e b.txt ] ; then
    rm b.txt
fi
echo "Bash:"
time bashtest
rm b.txt
echo
echo "Awk:"
time awktest
rm b.txt
echo
echo "Sed:"
time sedtest
```

where `bashtest` is

```
while read line
do
    echo "prefix_$line" >> b.txt
done < a.txt
```

`awktest` is:

```
awk '$0="myprefix_"$0' a.txt > b.txt
```

and `sedtest` is:

```
sed 's/^/myprefix_/' a.txt > b.txt
```

I got the following result on my machine:

```
Bash:

real    0m0.401s
user    0m0.340s
sys 0m0.048s

Awk:

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s

Sed:

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s
```

It seems like the `bash` solution is much slower..

Comment: +1 Spawning external programs is the purpose of a shell language. If you were calling `awk` once per line to prefix it, that would be overkill. But calling it once to process the entire file is fine.

Comment: This test would be more indicative of the performance differences if the bashtest were to process all lines in memory and then write to output file, rather than appending to the output file upon every line read.

Comment: @Psyrus Agree. Thanks for the remark! Feel free to update the answer with new timing results..

Comment: I have investigated, and will not edit the answer, as it turns out that string concatenation in memory with bash is ~twice as slow as the method you have proposed according to my tests (and since string concatenation is notoriously awful, actually makes sense).  A good answer btw, +1

Comment: For reference, the code I was using:`for line in $(<a.txt);
do;
  text+="prefix_$line\n";
done;
echo -e "$text" > b.txt;` Tried tweaking in various ways, all with either worse or similar results

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `xargs` utility:

```
cat file | xargs -d "\n" -L1 echo myprefix_
```

The `-d` option is used to allow input line with trailing blanks (related to `-L` spec).